# How to use OpenCV with python in OSX?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, opencv, sublimetext3

I wondering how can I import opencv libraries in python. I am using sublime3 but a noob to it. What I have tried is `import cv` in OSX terminal but the python quit unexpectedly with an error`Segmentation fault: 11`

My `$PATHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages` since I installed it with homebrew, so did opencv

Comment: please try to use cv2 instead of the outdated cv module. and $PATHONPATH is an obvious typo

Comment: @berak you again. I have solved it. Thx

Comment: edit your questios, and mark it as solved ?

Comment: @berak I answered myself. Hope to see you in my next question lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved since I imported the library in the system default python version carried by the OSX but my OpenCV was installed by an external python version. To change the default python version for your system, simply exports it to the $PATH

`$PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/`

It is the path I installed with homebrew. To check your default python version, you can type

`python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version)'`

in your terminal;

Besides, to use OpenCV in Sublime, builds a build-system with

```
{
    "path": "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin",
    "env": 
    {
        "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin"
    },
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Also, change the path in "path" and "env" of your own. Notice that the configuration data in build-system should be in JSON format like "env" does.

Wish this answer could be helpful.